# JQuery Map and JSON - Getting Sub Array Elements

Tags: jquery, json, geonames

I'm using JQuery to get city data from geonames.  My problem is when I want to extract the value for sub-array items when using the JQuery map function.

In this example, if I want to get the Wikipedia link, how could I do this?

I tried:
wikipedia: item.alternateNames.lang['link']

but didn't expect it would really work.  Does anyone know who I can extract the sub array items?

Here are the bits of code:

JSON RESULT

```
"geonames": [{
"alternateNames": [
  {
    "name": "Rancho Cucamonga",
    "lang": "en"
  },
  {
    "name": "91739",
    "lang": "post"
  },
  {
    "name": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rancho_Cucamonga%2C_California",
    "lang": "link"
  }

],
adminCode2": "071",
"countryName": "United States",
"adminCode1": "CA",
"fclName": "city, village,...",
"elevation": 368,
"score": 0.9999999403953552,
"countryCode": "US",
"lng": -117.5931084,
"adminName2": "San Bernardino County",
"adminName3": "",
"fcodeName": "populated place",
```

JQuery:

```
$("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {

                    response($.map(data.geonames, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name,
                            latitude: item.lat,
                            longitude: item.lng,

                            // problem here: how to get the value for the alternateNames.lang where lang = link
                            wikipedia: item.alternateNames.lang['link']

                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
```

Comment: As a side note, in the JSON your missing a quote before adminCode2.

Comment: Sorry, that came from cutting and pasting of code as I didn't want to put all of the data in the post.  On the actual data it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try...

```
wikipedia: item.alternateNames[2].name
```

But if you wanted to search them...

```
var name;
$.each( item.alternateNames, function(){
  if ( this.lang == 'link' ) {
    name = this.name;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much this worked perfectly.  Each entry might have several different alternateNames so I needed to find just the one with they key link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `alternateNames` is an array of objects, so you would have to use an index to retrieve an object from the array. Once you have the object you can retrieve the "lang" field:

```
item.alternateNames[2].lang
```

that should return you "link". This is assuming that `item` is the proper parent object of `alternateNames`.

Answer (score 0):

In same accident I find next solve:

Instead calling sub elements `lang` undo `map`, you can assigment only parent element `wikipedia: item.alternateNames`. And after, you can access to nested elements of them in select event of autocomplete.

This is my example:

```
$("#Customer_Name ").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("LookupCustomers", "Customers")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {

                            response($.map(data, function (item) {

                        //respose($.each(data, function (item

                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name,
                                id: item.Id,
                                phone: item.Phone,
                                addressStreet: item.AddressStreet,
                                addressBuilding: item.AddressBuilding,
                                addressHousing: item.AddressHousing,
                                addressFlat: item.AddressFlat,
                                metroStationId: item.MetroStationId,
                                metroStation: item.MetroStation  //trouble was here

                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                document.getElementById("Customer_Id").value = ui.item.id;
                document.getElementById("Customer_Name").value = ui.item.value;
                document.getElementById("Customer_Phone").value = ui.item.phone;
                document.getElementById("Customer_AddressStreet").value = ui.item.addressStreet;
                document.getElementById("Customer_AddressBuilding").value = ui.item.addressBuilding;
                document.getElementById("Customer_AddressHousing").value = ui.item.addressHousing;
                document.getElementById("Customer_AddressFlat").value = ui.item.addressFlat;
                document.getElementById("Customer_MetroStationId").value = ui.item.metroStationId;
                document.getElementById("Customer_MetroStation_Name").value = ui.item.metroStation.Name;  //and, trouble was here
            }
        });
```